# Why $\inf \{f^2(x) : x \in A\} = [\inf \{f(x) : x \in A\}^2]$

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to prove the integrability of $fg$ and I found that in most proof, they claim that
$$\inf \{f^2(x) : x \in A\} = \inf \{f(x) : x \in A\}^2$$
without proof and I am wondering how this can be proved. Thank you

Comment: It had to be pointed out that this can be wrong if $f$ can be negative.  Was $f$ nonnegative in the context of the proof?

Comment: No, so how can i proof, in general, if $f$ and $g$ are integrable, so does $fg$?

Comment: If you provide the source and/or content of the proof you already have, perhaps people here can help explain what they are doing.   You haven't said even what integrable means, i.e what type of integrability with what domain.  Riemann integration on an interval?

Answer (score 1):

This is false in general: suppose that $A=[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=x$. Then
$$ \inf\{x^2:x\in [-1,1]\}=0 $$
while
$$ (\inf\{x:x\in[-1,1]\})^2=(-1)^2=1$$

However, the claim is true if $f$ is a non-negative function.